# Prove that the dimension of $V$ is divisible by $3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over $\Bbb Q$ and let $T$ be non-singular linear transform on $V$ such that $T^{-1}=T^2+T$

> Prove that the dimension of $V$ is divisible by $3$.

If $\dim V=3$ then show that all such 
linear transformations are similar.

This question is exactly a  duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1710927/294365).

But the problem is I have encountered this problem only after having a course in Linear Algebra and so I don't know what is meant by finitely genearted modules over a PID and so on.

Can't it be solved using Linear Algebra techniques only.

Comment: Mark has deleted his answer, but it's basically correct.  It's not really important that $m(x)$ be the *minimal* polynomial of $T$, only that $\phi_T(x)$ has the same roots as an irreducible polynomial.  Since $m(x)$ is irreducible, whenever one is a root of a given polynomial, the other two are as well.  So you can keep dividing out copies of $m(x)$ until $\phi_T(x)/m(x)^r$ has no more roots (has degree zero).  This is entirely analogous to the idea that complex roots of a real polynomial always appear in conjugate pairs.

Comment: [see this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400670/dimension-of-mathbbq-vector-space-if-a-nonsingular-linear-transformation-t/2631370#2631370)